# Write header as first line at end of data

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort

Having a `read` loop that manipulate data from another function.

One of the tasks in the loop is to record widest text in "some columns".

At the end of the loop the width is printed out, *but the catch is to place it at top of output.*

This read loop is then again sorted and written to file.

So in short something like this:

```
get_data() {
    echo "3 A B C"
    echo "2 A BB C"
    echo "4 A B CCCC"
    echo "1 A B CC"
}

make_file() {
    file_out=$1
    {
        w3=0 # max width field 3
        w4=0 # max width field 4

        while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4; do
            [ "${#f3}" -gt "$w3" ] && w3=${#f3}
            [ "${#f4}" -gt "$w4" ] && w4=${#f4}
            # + various other manipulation of the data
            echo "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4"
        done< <(get_data)

        # Print width data at top of file:
        echo "$w3 $w4" >"$file_out"
    } | {
        #sed -u '$q'
        sort -n
    } >>"$file_out"
}

make_file test001
```

```
$ cat test001 
2 4
1 A B CC
2 A BB C
3 A B C
4 A B CCCC
```

Question is if this is safe in regards to the pipes etc? Could the last append `>>file_out` be called before the first `>file_out` (write of header data)?

For example; could the `stdout` be flushed in the `while read` loop and the `sort` and subsequent write be processed before `while` ends?